Let the cube be $ABCDA'B'C'D'$ and $P\in (AD)$. If $AE \perp BP$ and $CF \perp BP, E,F\in(BP)$, prove that $C'E=D'F$.
the question
Let the cube be $ABCDA'B'C'D'$ and $P\in (AD)$. If $AE \perp BP$ and $CF \perp BP, E,F\in(BP)$, prove that $C'E=D'F$.
my idea
drawing


I thought to use the theorem of the 3 perpendiculars and got that $C'F \perp PB$ and $A'E \perp PB$ And because $DD', CC' \perp (ABCD)$ and $DD'=CC'$ it enough to show that $DF=EC$ to show that $C'E=D'F$
I drew the above partial drawing of the plane $(ABCD)$ from here. I thought of doing some similarity like $AEP~CFB$ but got to nothing useful.
Hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

Show that $|BE|=|CF|$.

Just "complete" your sketch as shown below. What requested follows from the congruence of triangles $CFE$ and $DGF$.


@Intelligentipaica I demonstrated that ABCD is a rectangular, but how do i demonstrate its a square? Can you help me? Thank you!

@IONELABUCIU But ABCD is a square by definition (face of a cube), isn't it? Or perhaps did you mean $EFGH$?

@Intelligentipauca ohhh..yeah sorry i meant EFGH

For $EFGH$, start with $PAB\cong SBC\cong RCD\cong QDA$.

@Intelligentipauca I also thought of that. But how is $QA=SC=DR=PB$ going to help us?

Then you can prove $SFB\cong RGC\cong QHD\cong PEA$ and finally $EF\cong PB-PE-BF\cong CS-FS-CG\cong FG$.

Step 1: Utilize the Theorem of Three Perpendiculars
The theorem of three perpendiculars states
that if a line is perpendicular to a plane, then any line perpendicular to this line at its foot in the plane is also perpendicular to the plane.
Given:

$AE$ and $CF$ are both perpendicular to $BP$ and are within the plane $ABCD$.
$CC'$ and $DD'$ are perpendicular to plane $ABCD$, and $CC' = DD'$ because they are edges of the cube.

By the theorem, we get:

$C'F$ is perpendicular to $BP$ (because $CF$ is perpendicular to $BP$ and $C'F$ is collinear with $CF$).
Similarly, $A'E$ is perpendicular to $BP$.

Step 2: Show That $AP = CP$ and $EP = FP$
From Step 1, we know that $AE$ and $CF$ are perpendicular to $BP$ and that $AE = CF$ because they are edges of the cube.
In right triangles $AEP$ and $CFP$:

$\angle AEP = \angle CFP = 90^\circ$ (given).
$\angle PAE = \angle PCF$ because both angles are complementary to $\angle BAP$ and $\angle BCP$ respectively, and $\angle BAP = \angle BCP$ because $AB$ is parallel to $BC$ (sides of the cube).

Triangles $AEP$ and $CFP$ are similar by AA (Angle-Angle) similarity criterion.
Since $AE = CF$, the triangles are not only similar but also congruent by the hypotenuse-leg (HL) congruence criterion (right-angle hypotenuse and one other side).
By congruence, we have $AP = CP$ and $EP = FP$.
Step 3: Establish That $DF = EC$
Now, we'll consider triangles $DFP$ and $ECP$, which are also right triangles. We have established that $EP = FP$, and we know that $AE = CF$ (edges of the cube).
Triangles $DFP$ and $ECP$ are congruent by the HL criterion because:

$\angle DFP = \angle ECP = 90^\circ$ (by construction).
$DF$ and $EC$ are hypotenuses corresponding to legs $FP$ and $EP$ (which are equal).
$DD' = CC'$, which means $D$ and $C$ are equidistant from the plane $ABCD$.

By the congruence of these triangles, we have $DF = EC$.
Step 4: Conclude That $C'E = D'F$
Finally, we look at triangles $C'D'F$ and $C'EC$. These triangles are right triangles with $C'F$ and $A'E$ being the legs perpendicular to $BP$, and $CC'$ and $DD'$ being the equal corresponding legs.
By the Pythagorean theorem:

$C'D'F$ has sides $C'F$, $D'F$, and $DD'$.
$C'EC$ has sides $A'E$, $C'E$, and $CC'$.

Since $A'E = C'F$ (by congruence of $AEP$ and $CFP$) and $DD' = CC'$ (by the properties of the cube), the remaining sides must be equal to maintain the equality of the hypotenuses in the right triangles:
Therefore, $C'E = D'F$, completing the proof.

Hint
As $P$ is moved along $AD$, the loci of $E$ and $F$ are quarter-circles defined by the diameters $AB$ and $BC$ respectively.
